# How to get OracleDataClient in Silverlight App

Tags: c#, wcf

I am developing a silverlight 3 app with Oracle database in VS2010. But whenever I tried to add System.Data.OracleClient. I do not get it in Add Reference List. Why it is happening? Please help me out.

Comment: http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/12/Reusing-NET-Assemblies-in-Silverlight

Comment: Are people still writing Silverlight apps? Given that MS won't be pursuing its development...

Comment: Thanks. Actually, Silverlight dorectly doesn't support ADO.NET, that is why we cant add any System.Data.Sql/Oracle in silverlight. Rather use WCF instead. Thanks @slugster,@Mitch Wheat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight operates within a subset of the .Net framework, this means you are limited with what you can reference from a Silverlight assembly (as it is designed to be run within a browser, even OOB Silverlight apps still operate with this reduced framework).

What you will need to do is use WCF to communicate to a web service, and then do your Oracle work from there.